# How to print out the prompt to the user using MIPS

Tags: mips32

Write a MIPS assembly language program that prompts the user to input 3 integers and then prints out the average of the 3 numbers (integer division is OK for this problem). You do not need to validate the user input.

Can't seem to get the prompt for the user to show up in the console when running.

```html
.data
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter three numbers: "
    sum: .asciiz "The Sum is: "
    avg: .asciiz "The Avergae is: "
    
    
.text   
    # Read Integer
    li $v0, 5
    la $a0, prompt # Print String
    syscall
    
    #
    add $s0, $0, $v0
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    #
    add $s1, $0, $v0
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    #
    add $s2,$0,$v0
    add $s3, $s1, $s0
    add $s3, $s2, $s3
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sum
    syscall
    
    #
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, avg
    syscall
    
    #
    li $v0, 1
    addi $t1,$0, 3
    div $a0, $s3, $t1
    syscall
    
    #
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

[This here](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) says that the for the "output string" function, the value of $v0 before the syscall should be 4, not 5. Code 5 stands for "read integer".